# Applying java.util.function.Function to JSON Deserialization

Tags: java, json, functional-programming, jackson

I have a class that accept a *function* `Function<ByteBuffer, T> deserialize` as a constructor argument.

I want to create a function which converts JSON into a list of objects.

Here's what I am trying to do:

```java
public Function<ByteBuffer, List<MyObject>> deserialize(
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {

    return objectMapper.readValue(??, new TypeReference<List<MyObject>>(){});
}
```

Obviously the syntax is wrong here. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating such a *function* I would rather go with utility method because `ObjectMapper.readValue()` throws `IOException` which is checked. Therefore it should be handled because we can't propagate checked exceptions outside the `Function`.

If you wonder how it might look like, here it is:

```
public Function<ByteBuffer, List<MyObject>> deserialize(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {

    return buffer -> {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(buffer.array(),new TypeReference<List<MyObject>>() {
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

Instead, let's consider a utility-class:

```
public static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = // initializing the mapper

public static List<MyObject> deserialize(ByteBuffer buffer) throws IOException {
    
    return objectMapper.readValue(buffer.array(),new TypeReference<>() {});
}
```